# How to change this many to one relationship to one to one?

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I have two tables as in the snapshot below.

![Diagram][1]

**Scenario:**
A question should have only one correct answer, but can have many ( 3 in my case) wrong answers ( like a quiz show).

**Problem:**

`Questions` table has multiple answers in the `Answers` table, but only **one** correct answer. The correct answer is the `AnswerID` in `Questions` table and it is related to `AnswerID` column in `Answer` table.  But it shows up as a Many to One relationship ( please see the **bolded** fields).

I have applied UNIQUE constraint to AnswerID in Question table but still it shows a many to one relationship. What can I do so that each AnswerID column entry is linked to a single AnswerID in the Question table? or is this ok as it is?

Thank you

**QUESTIONS TABLE:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Questions](
        [QuestionID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [QuestionText] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
        [AnswerID] [int] UNIQUE NOT NULL,
        [ImageLocation] [ntext] NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Questions_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

**ANSWERS TABLE:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Answers](
    [AnswerID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AnswerText] [nchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [QuestionID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Answers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

Comment: Why don't you simply add a flag (RigtAnswer) in your Answer table? This will save you from extra checks (right answer is not in the list of possible answers...)

Comment: Please show us your FOREING KEY scripts as well.

Comment: @MauricioGracia I added a screen shot from SQL management studio

Comment: @iAteABug_And_iLiked_it see my answer to see if it is what you are looking for

Comment: I didn't read this line correct: Questions table has multiple answers in the Answers table, but only one correct answer. The AnswerId mislead me, because it should be CorrectAnswerId which suggest that multiple answers exists. Thought it was about one question, one answer. Thereby I removed my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach:

1. Drop the `QuestionID` from your `Answers` table.
2. Drop the `AnswerID` column from your `Questions` table.
3. Create a new table, `QuestionAnswer` (or something more meaninful, like `Exam`, `Test`, etc.), which has a `QuestionID`, an `AnswerID`, and an `IsCorrect` flag.
4. Map all `Answers` to their `Questions`, and mark which one is correct.

Now you can re-use answers for other questions as well, and every question and ever answer only exists once. It may also be useful if you want to add additional metadata about the question answer combinations. For example:

1. A `Sequence` column to control the order in which the answers appear.
2. A `PointValue` column to help produce a final score or grade.

Comment: Thanks. I like this approach better. Its reusable and feels more "normalized" to me.

Comment: This approach adds no benefits to the "Add [bool isCorrect] to Answers" approach (which *also* enables having multiple right answers). Also this approach makes deleting Answers a pain (you can never be sure if you can safely delete an answer, because another, not-yet-committed question being entered by another user might be referencing the answer you are about to delete), not to mention the complicated UI for enabling the re-usage of Answers. Converting logically owned relations to unowned only makes your life harder, not easier.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you want an `AnswerID` on your `Questions` table. You could add `IsCorrect` to the answers table, then have a unique constraint between `QuestionID` and `IsCorrect`, when is  `IsCorrect` is true.

Comment: True, or if you don't want duplicate answers in your answer table, you can add an `CorrectAnswerID` to the `Questions` table.

Comment: This also prevents the error of having a right AnswerId outside the range of all answers, which acts as a constraint and makes the model consistent even on database level.

Comment: @Reimius Not true if you create a filtered index and make it unique.

Comment: Looks like the question has been updated to address the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It should be OK as is.

To get all potential answers you join on Questions.QuestionID=Answers.QuestionID, to get the unique correct anser you instead join on Questions.AnswerID=Answers.AnswerID.

Answer (score 1):

Two options

1. Create foreign key column with the **UNIQUE and NOT NULL** constraints from the **QUESTIONS** table that references a **UNIQUE, NOT NULL column** in the **ANSWERS** table. This creates a 1:(0|1) relationship.
2. Remove the **bolded relationship** and add a IS_CORRECT_ANSWER column to your answers table to determine which answer is correct

For more details see 
[1:1 Foreign Key Constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32360/11-foreign-key-constraints)

Answer (score 0):

Answer table set AnswerId PK and FK to Questions(QuestionId)